# How to work on several machines, keep them in sync without Internet?

Tags: networking, version-control, cross-platform

For quite a while now, I have been using Dropbox to sync a Git repository on several virtual machines (one Windows, one Mac, one Linux). I would commit my changes on one of the machines and Dropbox would take care of syncing the changes of the files and the repo onto the other machines.

This works very seamless. I code on OSX, test the code on Windows and Linux, maybe make some changes there, then commit from one of the three.

However, it has three major drawbacks:

1. It requires an internet connection. I frequently have to rely on my cellphone for internet connectivity, which is unreliable if I'm on a train and only good for a few hundred Mb per month.
2. Dropbox syncs EVERYTHING including object files, Visual Studio debug databases and just a whole lot of unnecessary stuff that does not need to be synced.
3. It always goes through Dropbox servers, which is fine for some minor project or some open source stuff, but I don't want to push my work files to an untrusted server.

So, how do you manage an environment like this?

**Edit:**
Actually, all the three virtual machines live on the very same laptop, so network connections between them are not a problem. Also, I frequently code on one OS and compile on another--and go back and forth until I have found all errors. I don't want to spam the company repo with hundreds of incremental commits.

**Edit 2:**
To give you an idea for what I am looking for, here is a partial solution I came up with: On each machine, I created a git repository of the files I want to work with. Typically, I will start working on a bug/feature one machine, then commit my work. On the next machine, I will call `git reset origin` to load the changes from the first machine, then continue working on the commit using `git commit --amend`. This will go back and forth a few times. Once I am done, I will finally commit the changes for real (no more amending) and start working on the next feature/bug.

However, this workflow feels cumbersome and inelegant. What I am looking for is something that results in the same output--one commit on the repo--but was created fluently between the three machines.

Comment: Use a real GIT repo? Also, unless your machines are in the same place, this isn't going to be possible without some onboxiously long LAN cables!

Comment: Bitbucket, GitHub, Google Code... If you need a private git repo, Bitbucket has those free of charge. Why use Dropbox at all?

Comment: @mingos I can not use an internet repo to sync my machines since I don't always have an internet connection.

Comment: When you use git, you don't need to have your commits linear. I often forget to push my changes while I'm using one computer and then develop on the other. The advantage of DVCS is that the code will get merged anyway - for instance, when you have internet again.

Comment: @mingos right, but I can't use Github to synchronize two machines when I don't have internet.

Comment: You don't need Github, just create your own repo. You can still sync to Github when you do have a network connection if you like, but Git certainly doesn't require or try to enforce anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider setting up your own software versioning server.

Most clients for these servers have implementations on varying OS's and platforms. 
But if you want to communicate between machines that are not in a LAN, you're going to need an internet connection.

The versioning servers network communication can be exposed over NAT through a gateway to the internet. You could implement security by setting up a tunnel mechanism. Any client would then tunnel up to a gateway server and then communicate with the versioning server.

As for control over which files are actually versioned: I have some experience with SVN, with which you can select on file level which files to add to versioning. the SVN client will then simply ignore the rest of the files and directories.

**Edit:**

Reading the edit of the original author's question: 
Maybe setup a 4th virutal machine, containing the Versioning server. SVN isn't (by any stretch of the imagination) hard to manage. (RTM). Have the three virtual machines connect to the server on the 4th. (This is ofcourse, if it's possible to run the machines in parallel on the same machine.)

Comment: Git doesn't need a dedicated server, so this seems like a step backwards.

Comment: Then the 4th machine can be used as a fileserver / shared diskspace. The network based filetransfer to this machine should provide abstract interface to counter the headaches of setting up filesharing between the different platforms.

Comment: Still beg to differ. Not even SVN requires a network connection, let alone specifically a public Internet connection. Just `svnadmin create` a repo on a local disk, and use `file:///path/to/repo` as the URL for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share a disk between the three, put the master repo on that. (Make sure you make backups! Especially for removable media.)

**Edit**: In more detail, you can have your master repo on a USB stick or a shared partition on your hard drive (as you indicate you are using multiple virtual machines on the same hardware).

To set up a private `git` repo, simply create an empty directory and run `git init`.

Assuming you are on your Ubuntu box and have an USB stick with a file system which you can read and write in all your operating systems, mounted in `/media/usbgit`, run this:

```
vnix$ mkdir /media/usbgit/mycode
vnix$ cd /media/usbgit/mycode
vnix$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /media/usbgit/mycode/.git/
```

(Given that you already have a git repo, you probably just want to clone it to the USB stick instead:

```
vnix$ cd /media/usbgit
vnix$ git clone /home/you/work/wherever/mycode
Initialized empty Git repository in /media/usbgit/mycode/.git/
```

This will now contain all the commits from the repo you pulled from.)

Now you have an empty repository which you can clone and pull from on all the boxes.  Once you have the USB stick mounted, you can clone from it.

```
vnix$ cd
vnix$ mount | fgrep usbgit
/dev/whatever on /media/usbgit type NTFS (rw)
vnix$ git clone /media/usbgit/mycode
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/you/mycode/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

All of this is doable with SVN too (use `svnadmin create` to initialize a repository, and `svn checkout file:///media/usbgit/mycode` to check it out), but you will lose the benefits of a distributed VCS, which seem useful in your scenario.

In particular, with a distributed VCS, you can have multiple private repositories (each working directory is a repository on its own) and you can sync with and pull from your private master *and* a public repository e.g. on Github -- just make sure you know what you have where.